# How to consume/integrate third-party modules in Python

Tags: python, boto

I am new to Python and recently started writing a script which essentially reads a MySQL database and archives some files by uploading them to Amazon Glacier. I am using the Amazon-provided `boto` module along with a few other modules.

I noticed that I seem to be replicating the same pattern over and over again when installing and taking advantage of these modules that connect to external services. First, I write a wrapper module which reads my global config values and then defines a connection function, then I start writing functions in that module which perform the various tasks. For example, at the moment, my `boto` wrapper module is named `awsbox` and it consists of functions like `getConnection` and `glacierUpload`. Here's a brief example:

```
import config,sys,os
import boto,uuid

_awsConfig = config.get()['aws']

def getGlacierConnection():
  return boto.connect_glacier( aws_access_key_id=_awsConfig['access_key_id'],
                               aws_secret_access_key=_awsConfig['secret_access_key'])


def glacierUpload( filePath ):

  if not os.path.isfile( filePath ):
    return False

  awsConnect = getGlacierConnection()    

  vault = awsConnect.get_vault( _awsConfig['vault'] )

  vault.upload_archive( filePath )

  return True
```

My question is, should I be writing these "wrapper" modules? Is this the Pythonic way to consume these third-party modules? This method makes sense to me but I wonder if creating these interfaces makes my code less portable or modular, or whether or not there is a better way to integrate these various disparate modules into my main script structure.

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation is rather abstract. Can you show us some code to get a better idea of what you are doing?

Comment: I added a simple example, my `boto` wrapper module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the modules as intented. You import them and then use them. As I see it, `awsbox` is the module that holds the implementation of the functions that match your needs.

So answering your cuestion:

**should I be writing these "wrapper" modules?**, yes (you can stop calling them "wrappers"), an error would be to rewrite those installed  modules.

**Is this the Pythonic way to consume these third-party modules?**, Is the Python way. Authors write modules for you tu use(import).